# How to use android-support-v7-recyclerview without static linkage in Android.mk?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android.mk

I want to use RecyclerView to replace the list view in my code, and in Android.mk,  I use static link LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := android-support-v7-recyclerview, everything works well.

**But my boss said, we cannot use static linkage in our Android.mk**, so I tried to use LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES, but always meet NoClassDefFoundError.

How to use recyclerView without static linkage?

Thanks

Comment: Requirement is : Must change to dynamic linkage.

Comment: Crash error is ::  Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #90: Binary XML file line #90: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView"